# Meissner state placed in a uniform magnetic field B. Magnetic field distribution and superconducting current density of the sphere

Tags: plotting

The following figure depicts a superconducting sphere of radius 1 in an ideal Meissner state placed in a uniform magnetic field B. Magnetic field distribution in the outer vacuum, and the superconducting current density of the sphere.

[image]

Based on electrodynamics, I've already done part of the code

```mathematica
Clear["Global`*"];
(*=== 1. Define dimensionless variables ===*)
H0 = 1;
a = 1;
mu0 = 1;
R = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2];
\[Theta] = ArcCos[z/R];

(*=== 2. Define current and magnetic field ===*)
(*Current field*)
JMeissnerSpherical = {0, 0, -3/2*H0*Sin[theta]};
(*Transform the vector in the spherical coordinate system to the Cartesian coordinate system*)
JMeissnerCartesian =
  TransformedField["Spherical" -> "Cartesian",
   JMeissnerSpherical, {r, theta, phi} -> {x, y, z}];
(*Magnetic flux*)
\[CurlyPhi] = -H0 R Cos[\[Theta]] - (H0 a^3)/(2 R^2) Cos[\[Theta]];
(*Magnetic field*)
bB = -Grad[-\[CurlyPhi], {x, y, z}]*mu0;
(*=== 3. Plot the graph ====*)
dc = SliceVectorPlot3D[
   JMeissnerCartesian,
   "CenterSphere", {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
   VectorStyle -> {Red},
   VectorColorFunction -> None,
   PlotLegends -> {"Current"}];

cc = SliceVectorPlot3D[
   bB, {"YStackedPlanes", 1},
   {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, {z, -1.5, 1.5},
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 > 1],
   VectorStyle -> {Blue}, VectorColorFunction -> None,
   PlotLegends -> {"Magnetic field"}];
Show[dc, cc]
```

[image]

What I want to do now is draw exactly the same picture as in the textbook, so how do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly the same picture as in the book, but close:

```
StreamDensityPlot[(bB /. x -> 0)[[{2, 3}]], {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{y, z}, y^2 + z^2 > 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: A few things I tried to do to remove this orange background color didn't work, like `RegionBoundaryStyle`，`RegionFillingStyle`

Comment: For a white backround, add `, ColorFunction -> (White &)`

Comment: thans your help

Answer (score 2):

With @Daniel Huber help，I have succeeded in copying the pictures in the textbook，like this

```mathematica
tu1 = Show[
  SliceVectorPlot3D[
   JMeissnerCartesian, 
   "CenterSphere", {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
   VectorStyle -> {Red},
   VectorColorFunction -> None,
   Boxed -> False,
   Axes -> False],
  Axes -> False, ViewPoint -> Front]

StreamDensityPlot[(bB /. x -> 0)[[{2, 3}]],
 {y, -2, 2}, {z, -3, 3},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{y, z}, y^2 + z^2 > 1],
 StreamScale -> Full,
 AspectRatio -> 3/2,
 Background -> White,
 Frame -> False,
 ColorFunction -> (If[# < 0, White, Transparent] &),
 RegionFillingStyle -> None,
 RegionBoundaryStyle -> None,
 StreamStyle -> {Black, Arrowheads[0.025]},
 StreamColorFunction -> None,
 Epilog -> Inset[tu1]]
```

[image]